# How to run a tf.assign operation without pulling its result

Tags: tensorflow

It seems that `sess.run(tf.assign(...))` returns the new value of this variable. This seems inefficient as I don't need that value and the value is a large matrix. How can I execute the assignment without having its new value returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you give `sess.run()` an [`Operation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Operation) instead of a [`Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor), it will execute it and return `None` (instead of the `Tensor` values).

You can access the underlying `Operation` with the attribute [`op`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Tensor#op) of a `Tensor`.

```python
print(sess.run(tf.assign(...).op)
# > None
```

Comment: I'll try this and report back.